# Globalization .net convert string to double

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

İ have string like this and i want to convert it to double.

```
string x = "65.50";
double y = Convert.ToDouble(x);
```

But the result is 6550.0

i want it to be 65.50.

I am using ASP.NET and C#. I think it is a problem about globalization.

This is my for question sorry about that (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's your current culture that converts it this way. You can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to skip using your culture.

```
double d = double.Parse("65.50", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

> i want it to be 65.50.

If you want to convert it back to string:

```
string str = d.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I assume this is a currency since you keep the decimal places. Then you should use `decimal` instead:

```
decimal dec = decimal.Parse("65.50", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 65.5
```

Now you can use `decimal.ToString` and it automagically restores the decimal places:

```
string str = dec.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // "65.50"
```

Comment: it was worked. thank you very much. but in my project i use lost of code like this. do i write this on everywhere when i want to convert. or any other way to do this.

Comment: i think i need to format my pc and set all my regional setting to USA format (:

Comment: You can change the culture once in this way: `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");`

Answer (score 1):

Recently i had a similar problem. The solution :

```
var result = Double.TryParse(x, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out y);
```

if you get true, that's x is converted to double

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var res =  Double.Parse("65.50", NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It will parse it with culture where `.` is floating separator

Here you can try it: http://ideone.com/3LMVqa